# Concurrency level of VARRAY vs Nested tables

Tags: oracle, concurrency, nested-table, varray

I'd like to know what would have a better concurrency level, VARRAY or nested tables. Is it really true that VARRAY only need one input/output operation ot load the collection?

It's for a reservations systems.

Regards,

Comment: You might get a more detailed answer if you explain what you mean when you ask about "Concurrency Level" as most databases (including Oracle) have ACID properties which means that there is [atomicity in transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/transact.htm#CNCPT016). When you are asking about I/O operations are you asking at the transaction level (i.e. DML statements) or are you asking about disk I/O?

Comment: Hi, I'm asking about transaction level. Sorry for not being enough clear.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it really true that VARRAY only need one input/output operation ot load the collection?

Define a `VARRAY` and a collection type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE test_varray AS VARRAY(3) OF NUMBER;
CREATE TYPE test_collection AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

Then you can create similar tables for each of those data types:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test1 (
  id    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  array test_varray
);

CREATE TABLE test2 (
  id    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  array test_collection
) NESTED TABLE array STORE AS test2__array;
```

You can `INSERT` into those tables as a single statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO test1 ( id, array ) VALUES ( 1, test_varray( 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 ) );
INSERT INTO test2 ( id, array ) VALUES ( 1, test_collection( 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 ) );
```

You can `SELECT` from those tables as a single statement:

```sql
SELECT id, column_value FROM test1 CROSS JOIN TABLE( array );
SELECT id, column_value FROM test2 CROSS JOIN TABLE( array );
```

Which both output:

> ```
> ID | COLUMN_VALUE
> -: | -----------:
>  1 |          1.1
>  1 |          1.2
>  1 |          1.3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cc5cdbe027bb6ae107fcd0ab581d6932)*

So from a point of `INSERT`/`SELECT` operations they are functionally similar. The [Oracle Documentation - Understanding PL/SQL Collection Types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS00501) explains some of the differences mainly:

- `VARRAY` has a bounded number of elements and is always dense.
- Collections (Nested Tables) can have an unbounded number of elements and could be sparse.